# cakephp - order by a field in the contained Model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to get all the products which are in a particular category (products hasandbelongstomany Catrgories). My conditions are the Category.name='whatever' and the Product.live=1

I can do this like this:

```
$cats = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.name' => $categoryName
    ),
    'contain' => 'Product.live = 1'
));
```

But I also want to sort the results by Product.sort_order, so I tried:

```
$cats = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.name' => $categoryName
    ),
    'order' => array('Product.sort_order'),
    'contain' => 'Product.live = 1'
));
```

But this doesn't work. Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

**TLDR:**  Use Joins instead of Contain (or swap the direction of find)

I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721136/cakephp-containable-conditions-not-limiting-results/15721973#15721973) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988483/conditions-in-joined-tables-shows-error-cakephp/22990210#22990210) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190385/grouping-contained-models/15191835#15191835) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165364/cakephp-contain-association-conditions-issue/13165682#13165682) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848551/cakephp-find-with-contain/24853919#24853919)[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579406/cakephp-1-3-contain-not-building-associations-correctly/15583356#15583356) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123018/cakephp-2-1-find-using-contain-with-condition/14123683#14123683) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311204/how-to-get-data-from-different-associated-tables-using-containable-in-cakephp/20313580#20313580) [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906181/cakephp-models-with-associated-conditions/14907548#14907548) Overflow - not sure if it's just not coming up in [searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=user%3A673664%20contain%20join)...etc or what, but - you can't order by a Contained model because Containing usually creates multiple/separate queries.

Comment: OMG @scrowler - you found and linked them all.  I wish I could +1 you for that.  Made me LOL.